# How can I vectorize this simple algorithm with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, vectorization

Or are truly iterative algorithms like this not vectorizable?

s += usage can be vectorized with cumsum, but the floor on the sum is problematic.

Is there some fancy way to use lags or shifting?

```
s = 0
for (time, usage) in timeseries:
    s += usage
    s = max(s-rate, 0)
    new_timeseries[time] = s
```

I pryed away at it for a while but couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Put `timeseries` into an array first. Let's assume the values of `timeseries` are `my_array`. Then,

```
import numpy as np
s = np.cumsum(my_array) - rate
s[s < 0] = 0
new_timeseries = s
```

**UPDATE:** this is not right. It doesn't account for zeroing the `cumsum` when `s` the increment is below the rate. You can find the points where the `cumsum` is below rate with the derivative:

```
In [1]: dd = np.diff(np.cumsum(my_array))
In [2]: dd < rate
Out[3]: array([ True, False, True, False, False, True, True,  
                True, True, False, True, False, True, False,
                True, True, True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

However, this doesn't 'reset' the `cumsum`. One could hunt along those indices and do a `cumsum` in blocks of 'Trues', but I'm not sure if it would be more efficient than your loop.

Comment: it seems to be incorrect. It overestimates sums that follow `s < rate` sums.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, you are right, I missed that part. Even my latest edit is not right.

Comment: usage is always > 0, i should have mentioned. np.diff(np.cumsum(a)) = a no? this doesn't quite seem complete (which you acknowledge in your answer). i hadn't seen np.diff before though thanks.